# Get email from non default inbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using the following vba code to get emails from my inbox folder and move them to a sub folder called suppliers. At the moment the emails are moved from my default email inbox,  but I have an account called purcashing@hewden.co.uk and I want it to get the emails from this inbox and move it to the subfolder called Suppliers in this account.

can someone show me how I would alter GetDefaultFolder to make this happen. thanks

```
Sub MoveItems()
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim myItem As Object


 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myItems = myInbox.Items
 Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Supplier")
 Set myItem = myItems.Find("[Subject] = 'Introduction'")
 While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
 myItem.Move myDestFolder
 Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
 Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Namespace.GetDefaultFolder, retrieve the appropriate store from the Namespace.Stores collection and use Store.GetDefaultFolder.

Comment: Not GetDefaultFolder, but GetRootFolder. Store does not have GetDefaultFolder method.

Comment: Store.GetDefaultFolder was added in Outlook 2010. Store.GetRootFolder and then opening the folder by name will not work in a localized environment.

Comment: The OP didn't mention Office version, so GetRootFolder would work in either 2007 and 2010+.

Comment: Keep in mind that Outlook 2007 is no longer supported by Microsoft - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=Outlook%202007&wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

I just used Dmitry's suggestion and it works like a charm.

Hope it helps \o/

```
Sub GetEmailFromNonDefaultInbox()
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
    Dim strFilter As String

    ' let the user choose which account to use
    Set myAccounts = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Stores
    For i = 1 To myAccounts.count
        res = MsgBox(myAccounts.Item(i).DisplayName & "?", vbYesNo)
        If res = vbYes Then
            Set myInbox = myAccounts.Item(i).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If myInbox Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' avoid error if no account is chosen

    ' query emails by subject
    strFilter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" like '%YOUR SUBJECT%'"
    Set myitems = myInbox.Items.Restrict(strFilter)

    ' show some feedback if no email is found
    If myitems.count = 0 Then 
        MsgBox "Nothing found. Try another account."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' get the most recent email
    myitems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
    Set myitem = myitems.GetFirst
    If myitem.Class = olMail Then
        ' and now you can do whatever you want
        MsgBox (myitem.Subject)
    End If
End Sub
```